# Is this the correct way to capture paypals subscribers id with IPN?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Im trying to capture the subscribers id. Once the client subscribes and gets sent to the ipn page, the subscribers id does not echo!

```
<?php
      // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    // assign posted variables to local variables



      ////////////////////////////////////////////HERE
    $payer_id= $_POST['subscr_id'];
      echo 'id='.$payer_id;


      ///////////////////////////////////////////



    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
      if("subscr_cancel" == $_POST['txn_type']){

    if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR
    } else {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

                     $websites= "websites";
        $database = "k29803_1";
       mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db($database);

      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= secret AND password = secret ";
      $results = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($results)==1){
            $add_credits = "UPDATE users SET credits = credits -5000
            WHERE username= 'drahoslava' AND password = 'drah0slava'";
            mysql_query($add_credits) or die(mysql_error());


          }

    }
    else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    }
    }
    fclose ($fp);
    }
      }
      ?>
```

The button looks like this

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="NQMGM2LCZUQRE">

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="01" />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.99" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

How can i get the subscribes id to echo? Is something wrong with the button? Should it have a notify_url?

This is what i get posted back

```
http://www.germcode.kodingen.com/ipn.php?tx=7ND09573SF680804M&st=Completed&amt=2.99&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=&sig=J1J%2f4phZ1VlJI1NcHAU3HxEjMgvWbv8aenml17e0GEGWfOy1CbyvaTQw60qXMf6l%2bL0LZ4GESLX6VikG%2f6UronEGf5lmKzWoXePPYdd%2bV3ep%2fXwTplJlez3NuNAxWYUHr0FGd35s15ZdTp4bOaA2yZfpWg2iLGDMQi6IN9%2f%2f8N0%3d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting posted back is not IPN data. You'll want to set up `notify_url` within your PayPal form in order to receive IPN data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.germcode.kodingen.com/ipn.php">
```

Note: If you're using a so called 'hosted button' (all details are stored with PayPal), you can also set up IPN within your PayPal Profile, or go to the button management tool, click on Step 3, tick "Add advanced variables" and add `notify_url=http://www.germcode.kodingen.com/ipn.php` in the textarea.